# In AWS Step Functions, how can I pass numbers to a Map iterator Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I currently have 2 Lambda functions in a Step Function. One always returns an array of numbers:

```js
export const handler = async(event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: [1, 2, 3]
    };
    return response;
};
```

The number elements are passed to a `Map` state, where an iterator function adds 1 to the input:

```js
export const handler = async(event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: event + 1,
    };
    return response;
};
```

I have set up a Step Function to run the 1st function and then run the 2nd function on each element of the output array:

```json
{
  "StartAt": "return array",
  "States": {
    "return array": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "...return-array:$LATEST"
      },
      "Retry": [
        ...
      ],
      "Next": "Map"
    },
    "Map": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "add",
        "States": {
          "add": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
            "Parameters": {
              "Payload.$": "$",
              "FunctionName": "...add:$LATEST"
            },
            "Retry": [
              ...
            ],
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "ItemsPath": "$.body"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'add' (entered at the event id #12). The Parameters '{"FunctionName":"...add:$LATEST","Payload":1}' could not be used to start the Task: [The value for the field 'Payload' must be a STRING]
```

It looks like the fix should be easy enough but I can't seem to figure out how to convert each element of `[1, 2, 3]` to a string before passing it to the next step.

Comment: Is `body:  body: [1, 2, 3]` a typo? And what body do you actually want? `"[1, 2, 3]"` or `["1", "2", "3"]` or something else?

Comment: hm something wrong with that? lambda function seems to be working fine.

Comment: It's not valid JavaScript and will result in an uncaught SyntaxError.

Comment: oh, sorry, of course, it's supposed to be body: [1, 2, 3]. corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, your Map state passes `number` scalars to each iteration, but the `Payload` expects key-values or a string.

Convert the number payload (at path `$`) to a string with the `JsonToString` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) in the `add` Lambda task's parameters:

```json
 "add": {
    "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "States.JsonToString($)",
        "FunctionName": "...add:$LATEST"
    }
    ...
 }
```

Your Lambda now receives a stringified number as its `event`.  Modify your `add` handler code accordingly:  `body: parseInt(event,10) + 1` to convert the `event` back to a number.

---

Alternatively, you could replace your `add` Lambda task with a `Pass` state as the Map's iterator.  The trick is another intrinsic function, `MathAdd`.  `MathAdd` accepts two numbers, so there's no type conversion hassle:

```json
"Add": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Parameters": {
    "add.$": "States.MathAdd($, 1)"
  },
  "OutputPath": "$.add",
  "Next": "AnotherTask"
},
```

Comment: thx! it worked when i modified definition directly (1st solution). Is there a solution that can be done within the Workflow Studio? maybe an extra step?

Comment: @shadesofdarkred Glad to help.  I am not familiar with Workflow Studio.